# How to update cluster's IP addresses in Dynatrace Managed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, dynatrace

I've been looking to see if there's a way to backup my dynatrace managed install by taking snapshots of the EC2's volumes.

However, it seems that when I try to bring up the cluster from the snapshots, it goes haywire since all the private IP addresses have changed, and the cluster and servers can't function. I've tried manually hacking through the config files and changing all the old IP addresses to the new ones. After enough hacking I got it to a point where the console would at least let me log in, but when looking at the cluster through the console it still had the old IP addresses, and showed errors with all nodes in the cluster. I think this guy did something similar: https://community.dynatrace.com/t5/Dynatrace-Open-Q-A/How-can-we-change-IP-address-of-Dynatrace-Managed-Cluster-server/m-p/85423/highlight/true#M5176

The main reason I am trying to create my own system for making backups with snapshots is because the default backups only let you do daily backups, and I would like to see if I could do backups more often.

Is there a way to update Dynatrace Managed's Cluster IP Addresses via ssh? I'm looking for a way by ssh into each cluster node, fixing the IP addresses, then restarting the dynatrace node.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to do this from an EC2 or VM snapshot. The daily backup is only the full backup. There's already a differential/incremental backup taken every 2 hours (it used to be every hour, but this was too frequent for larger clusters to complete in time before the next increment).

The only scenario you can change the existing IP is a restore from backup scenario (yes, the built-in backup). And, this would involve running the process here: https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/shortlink/managed-cluster-restore#restore-from-backup

Noting, that *if you were to use a snapshot to restore the VM* then you would first have to uninstall Dynatrace from that replaced VM anyway, before running the restore. This implies deleting all data as part of the uninstall. Therefore, your attempts to use snapshotting for this would be fruitless.

This process also takes many hours on a multi-node cluster setup with lots of existing data. You must first stop any running nodes in the cluster, because changing the IP of even just one node, you need to inform all other nodes of the new locations (IP addresses) of other nodes through the restore mode. It's also why it's only really recommended to use it during a full cluster loss (such as data centre loss).

If you are running a multi-node cluster of at least 5 nodes, and your concern for your backup & restore to a new VM with new IP is really only for a situation where you lose 1 VM, you are probably better of to simply add a new node through replication and manually cleanup/remove the old node. Better yet, set up rack-awareness for the cluster to make it more resilient for 9 nodes or more.